# Pybind11 : return c++ 3d array as numpy array in python

Tags: c++, arrays, numpy, pybind11

I am calling c++ function from python using pybind11 and it has to return a multidimensional array as a numpy array. Array is int array[100][100][3].

Also what if I just have a pointer to that array? How do I return it to python as a numpy array? I would try to avoid any copying if possible.

Comment: Have you read the pybind11 docs about using numpy? https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html

Comment: Yes. I was able to get it working. But now I have another problem. I am using py::array_t with array pointer and for some reason the values of the array are being changed while returning. Any idea why? I guess I am messing up strides? I am using strides as {100*3*4, 3*4, 4}, 4 for int, 3 is last dimension, 100 is columns.

Comment: I posted this as a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961331/pybind11-returning-c-array-as-numpy-array-changes-values.