# PyBind11 : returning c++ array as numpy array changes values

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, pybind11

I am calling c++ function from python using pybind11 and it has to return a multidimensional array as a numpy array. Array is int array[100][100][3].

I am using a pointer to the array in py::array_t constructor and able to successfully return a numpy array in python. But the values in python are being changed for some reason.

```
return py::array_t<int>( {100, 100, 3}, // shape
                         {100*3*4, 3*4, 4}, // C-style contiguous strides
                         pointer // the data pointer
                        );
```

Also, I tried to create a single dimension array[100 x 100 x 3] and used:

```
return py::array_t<int>( {100*100*3}, // shape
                         {4}, // C-style contiguous strides
                         pointer // the data pointer
                        );
```

After getting the array as numpy array in python, I tried to change the shape to my needs using array.reshape((100,100,3)) and also .view() method like its mentioned here :
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html. But no luck.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? I would try to avoid any copying if possible.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible sample. It's not clear what pointer is in this context.

Comment: Its pointer to int array[100][100][3]. But anyways I was able to fix the issue of strides.