# Pybind11 : available array_t constructors

Tags: python, c++11, pybind11

I want to create an array_t from a double* and size.

I did not find a constructor mentioned explicitely in the docs.

I tried to copy this thread : [PyBind11 : returning c++ array as numpy array changes values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961331/pybind11-returning-c-array-as-numpy-array-changes-values)

But when I try, I get an error :
fatal error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'py::array_t'
py::array_t test = py::array_t({size, DIM},{DIM*8, 8}, data);

where size and dim are unsigned int and data is a double*.

How can I construct an array_t, and, more importantly, where is this information available ?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases I got lucky and the compiler told me which constructors were available.

The solution here was to make sure that the shape and stride were correct :

```
py::array_t test = py::array_t({(int) size,(int) DIM},{(int) DIM*8, 8}, data);
```